How to setup DuplicateMessageFilter for a single appender
I have a situation where I only want to use the turbo filter DuplicateMessageFilter for a single appender. (among console and file, only for console). How can I set it up?
I can only think of create a custom filter copying the class and using that. Is there another way?
